# Sudden Problems with TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

After installing all of the new updates available in TexLive about an hour ago (23/3/14 - previous update 19/3/14), I'm having trouble with some of my TOC entries.  When I have a figure with a separate TOC entry that involves a `\ce{}` environment, I get error messages saying that the control sequence `\aaaa` is not defined.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{book}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}  

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
pretty picture
\caption[X-ray crystal structure of [Rh(acac)\ce{(MCP)2}{]}.]{X-ray crystal structure of [Rh(acac)\ce{(MCP)2}].}
\label{fig:fig2p2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've tried using `\texorpdfstring`, but I end up with the same problem.  I've gone back to older copies of the file that were working fine last night, but I have the same problem.

I suspect that one of the updates I've just installed has done something to cause this, but I have no idea which one, or how to fix it.  Please help!!

I'm using texshop, compiling using dvi.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: With latest miktex, your code works for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: It compiles fine here with a recently updated installation of TeX Live. However, there is a more recent version of `mhchem` now available which I don't have. Perhaps somebody with a current installation could check for issues? Normally I would run an update but I can't afford the risk right now.

Comment: try deleting the `toc`, `aux`, and other 'cruft' files; it can often make a difference

Comment: I've tried deleting everything but the .tex file, and I'm still having the same problem.  I also get the same problem when I use tex works instead of texshop.  I'm about to reinstall everything that comes in the mactex download, hopefully that helps!

Comment: Reinstalling seems to have worked, so it was probably one of the updates I downloaded earlier today which killed it.  No idea which one though!

Answer (score 0):

exact duplicate of [Since few days: Trouble with mhchem using \listoftables or \listoffigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168001)

v3.16 was buggy. Install v3.17 which is currently on its way to your nearest CTAN server.