# Since few days: Trouble with mhchem using \listoftables or \listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, mhchem

I'm having trouble with the `mhchem` package. When I have a figure with a separate TOC entry that involves a `\ce{}` environment, I get error messages saying that the control sequence `\aaaa` is not defined. Few days ago another one have had the same problems, solved by reinstalling MiKTeX, but this does not work for me. At home, with an older version of the packages the MWE works, but in the new version it does not.
Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}  
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
test
\caption[\ce{SiO2}]{\ce{SiO2}}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!
The same Version of the document was running without any problems a few days ago!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You probably need to protect `\ce`: `\caption[\protect\ce{SiO2}]{\ce{SiO2}}`

Comment: Doesn´t work for me... The problem is related to a really long document with many many formulas ... It would be a mess, if i would have to edit every single caption.

Comment: works for your MWE (the `*.lof` file needs to be rewritten of course, so _two_ compilations are necessary before the error disappears)

Comment: Did you have the error for the non-edited MWE and then no error with \protect? Really? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes I had the error with your MWE and it vanished with `\protect` and compiling twice. In the first compilation the old `lof` file is used and thus the error still occurs. In the second compilation the new `lof` file is used which compiles correctly.

Comment: Hm, deleted all .toc, .nlo, .bak. etc. files, compiling once, twice, ... works not for me.

Comment: With the MWE that you posted above? If you have a different file which still produces the error then either your MWE is not accurate or you have to protect `\ce` in other places, too, like for example in section headings

Comment: I transferred the MWE from my TexnicCenter to this site via copy-paste, the file I am using is identical to the one I postet above - checked twice! There are no other places to \protect

Comment: Here the result in my .lof-file: \contentsline {figure}{\numberline {0.1}{\ignorespaces \aaaa {SiO2}}}{3}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that there is some mistyping in a new version of the package. I enclose a patch of what I think should be used there.

```
%! *latex malmhchem.tex
%   two runs
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}  
\begin{document}
\def\aaaa#1{\ce{#1}}
\chapter{Chemistry}
\section{My mhchem}
Some text.
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering Testing phase.
\caption[\ce{SiO2}]{\ce{SiO2}}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Wow, you´re great - it works!! Thanks a lot! (It is the really first time that I had to post a question by myself in 5 years of using LateX...)

Answer (score 2):

Ooooops! Version 3.17 fixes that and will become available soon.

```
2014-03-27 mhchem v3.17
• fix of the 3.16 expansion fix – sorry, my quality control failed
```